# chromium does not show self-signed certificate in certificate manager?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, certificate

I have imported a self-signed certificate into chrome (chromium on ubuntu) and I would like to remove it now. but I can not find it anywhere in the certificate manager. is there any programmatic or other way to do it?